# Problem with PS Insights: Low-resolution images and inadequate contrast

Tags: image, background, size, resolution, foreground

I'm facing an issue with PageSpeed Insights on my website and I would need your help to resolve it. The PageSpeed Insights report shows two problems that I'm trying to address:

"Displays images with low resolution: To maximize image clarity, the normal dimensions of the image should be proportional to the screen size and pixel ratio."

"Background and foreground colors do not have adequate contrast ratio: Text with low contrast is difficult or impossible to read for many users."

I have followed the recommendations to optimize the images and improve the resolution, but I haven't been able to solve the problem yet. Additionally, I would like to address the issue of inadequate contrast between the background and foreground colors on my website.

Here is a link to my website so you can take a look at the PageSpeed Insights report: [[Insights Report](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-fotov60-com/2h2muboo1g?hl=es&form_factor=mobile)]

If any of you have experience in solving color contrast issues and can provide tips or guidelines on how to improve the contrast between the background and foreground colors in my custom theme, it would be greatly appreciated!

I appreciate any additional guidance you can provide to resolve these issues with PageSpeed Insights. Thank you for your support and advice!

Regards, fotov60

I have tried adding style="max-width: 147px; height: 47;" to the images to give them a size, but Insights still expects a larger size. If I upload a larger image, Insights asks for an even larger size. I hope to find a way to solve the problem that is causing this warning.

Answer (score 1):

I see that 6 months have passed since your question, but I would like to share the solutions I have learned in case new users encounter the same errors.

1- Here is the solution for the Low-resolution images problem: If the rendered size wxh ratio is set to 1 or 2 times less than the intrinsic wxh ratio (Maybe you have 480x360px intrinsic size than you give 280x210px), the problem seems to be solved. (At least for me it is. But actually its doesnt make sense)

2- I can say that it would be beneficial to cooperate with ChatGPT for the inadequate contrast problem. ChatGPT will tell you which colors will contrast with each other with suggestions.

Fixing: Here is the how fix your low resolution problem for images; https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11936

This is the final solution.